# Action Function is not working without rerender

Tags: apex, visualforce

would any one please explain me why action function is not working without "rerender" attribute.If it works it is showing null values.
Even it works fine with empty rerender attribute.

```
  <apex:actionFunction name="hai" action="{!actnfn}" rerender="">
    <apex:param name="one" value="" />
  </apex:actionFunction>
```

Comment: This unexpected behaviour has been there for a long time; see e.g. [apex:actionFunction and apex:param - Or How to Pass Values from Javascript to an Apex Controller](http://www.laceysnr.com/2010/11/apexactionfunction-and-apexparam-or-how.html).